# Generic method returning the position of max object in a list using a iterator

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

Im making a generic method that can take any type of list and find the position of the max value in that list, this is part of a bigger program I have made and I have made a iterator that I use to run through the list. Im nearly finished but Im having two problems: 1. I cant initialize the iterator inside the generic method. 2. Cant get the first value from the list.
Im not good at explaining, instead I commented the problem areas in the code. Any help is much appreciated!

The generic method:

```
 public static <T> int max(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
  {


      if (list == null)
      {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      int m = 0; // index max value
      T maxvalue = list[0]; // max value (error: How do it get the value of the list here?)
      int counter = 0;

      Iterator<T> it = new DobbeltLenketListeIterator(); //( error: cannot be referenced from a static context)

      while(it.hasNext()) 
      {
          counter++;

          if (c.compare(it.next(), maxvalue) > 0)
          {
              maxvalue = it.next;

              m = counter;
          }


      }


      return m;

  }
```

The iterator:

```
 private class DoublelinkedlistIterator implements Iterator<T>
  {
    private Node<T> p;
    private boolean removeOK;


    private DoublelinkedlistIterator()
    {
      p = head;        
      removeOK = false;  

    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {

        if(p.next != null )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public T next()
    {


      if( hasNext() == false)
      {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      Node<T> q = p;

      p = p.next;
      removeOK = true;
      return q.value;


    }

    public void remove()
    {

      if(!removeOK) throw new IllegalStateException("illegal!");

      removeOK = false;
      Node<T> q = head;

      if(head.next == p)
      {
          head = head.next;
          if(p== null) tale = null;
      }
      else
      {
          Node<T> r = head;
          while (r.next.next != p)
          {
              r = r.next;
          }

          q= r.next;
          r.next = p;
          if(p== null) tale = r;
      }

      q.value = null;
      q.value = null;

    }

  }  

  public Iterator<T> iterator()
  {
    return new DoublelinkedlistIterator();
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator(int index)
  {
      indexcontrol(index);
   Iterator<T> it = new DoublelinkedlistIterator();
      for (int i = 0; i < index && it.hasNext(); i++, it.next()); 
          return it;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hard one but I got some help, the answer is:
Iterator it = list.iterator();

T maxvalue = it.next();

Thank you both I appreciated your answers!

Comment: If your question has been "answered", you should "accept" the best answer, even if it is your own.

Answer (score 1):

1. mark your inner class as `static` also :

   `private static class DoublelinkedlistIterator implements Iterator<T>`
2. You tried to retrieve the first element of the List as an array element. You should write it like this instead :

   `T maxvalue = list.get(0);`

Comment: Its giving me ok on the list thanks, but the same problem as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try making these two changes:

Make your iterator class `static` and give it a generic parameter `T`:

```
private static class DoublelinkedlistIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
```

Then when you use it pass it the type:

```
Iterator<T> it = new DobbeltLenketListeIterator<T>();
```

Comment: A lot of lines in the iterator is giving me errors with the class definiton change.

Comment: What are the errors saying? Can you post code of your iterator class that's not compiling?